# Rails. Delayed_job funciona con dos horas de diferencia

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

Estoy implementando tareas de automatización de envío de emails a una hora determinada con esta gema de la siguiente manera:

```
def create
    @competition = Competition.new(competition_params)
    if @competition.save
      @competition.delay(run_at: @competition.startdate).start_competition
      @competition.delay(run_at: @competition.deadline).finish_competition
    .....
end
```

Tanto `start_competition` como `finish_competition` son dos métodos que envían un correo en aviso de que empieza y termina la competición, respectivamente.

Bien, pues todo se hace correctamente, pero el envío se hace dos horas más tarde de lo que hay guardado tanto en `startdate` como en `deadline`.
Sé que esto pasa por mi zona horaria, que es `+02:00`, por lo que por ejemplo, si `stardate` yo la pongo, al crear una competición, a las  09:50, el email se  mandará a las 11:50.

De la misma forma y revisando esto, me he dado cuenta que cuando creo cualquier objeto de la app, tanto `created_at` como `updated_up` se crean con `datetime +00:00`. Es decir, que si yo creo una competición a las `19:00` de hoy, `created_at` será igual a `2017-07-20 17:00:00`.

¿Cómo puedo arreglar esto?

#### Ejemplo

Tengo por un lado el siguiente `delayed_job` correspondiente al primero de ellos (el que ejecuta `start_competition`)

```
  #<Delayed::Backend::ActiveRecord::Job 
        id: 35, 
        priority: 0, 
        attempts: 0, 
        handler: "--- !ruby/object:Delayed::PerformableMethod\nobject...", 
        last_error: nil, 
        run_at: "2017-07-20 08:30:00", 
        locked_at: nil, 
        failed_at: nil, 
        locked_by: nil, 
        queue: nil, 
        created_at: "2017-07-20 06:24:38", 
        updated_at: "2017-07-20 06:24:38">
```

Como ven, lo programé para ejecutarse a las `08:30`, y el correo me llegó a las `10:30`. También lo cree a las `08:24` y se guardó `created_at` como `06:24`.

Por otro lado, el correspondiente al segundo de ellos (el que ejecuta `finish_competition`)

```
  #<Delayed::Backend::ActiveRecord::Job 
        id: 36, 
        priority: 0, 
        attempts: 0, 
        handler: "--- !ruby/object:Delayed::PerformableMethod\nobject...", 
        last_error: nil, 
        run_at: "2017-07-20 08:31:00", 
        locked_at: nil, 
        failed_at: nil, 
        locked_by: nil, 
        queue: nil, 
        created_at: "2017-07-20 06:24:38", 
        updated_at: "2017-07-20 06:24:38">
```

Como ven, lo programé para ejecutarse a las `08:31`, y el correo me llegó a las `10:31`. También lo cree a las `08:24` y se guardó `created_at` como `06:24` (ya que se crea en el mismo momento que el primero).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tal como lo comentas, el problema se debe a la diferencia que hay entre tu zona horaria y la que tienes configurada en tu aplicación, tanto en **Rails** como en **ActiveRecord**.

Para solucionarlo debes especificar tu zona horaria (en ambos casos), agregando/modificando estas líneas en el archivo *config/application.rb*:

```
config.time_zone = "Mexico City"
config.active_record.default_timezone = :local
```

En el ejemplo utilicé `Mexico City` como zona horaria (que es mi hora local), así que reemplaza esa zona por la que corresponde a tu localidad; para encontrarla puedes ejecutar el siguiente comando:

```
$ rake time:zones:all
```

**Importante**: debes reiniciar el servidor de Rails después de modificar `application.rb` para que los cambios hagan efecto.

Comment: Funcionó! Muchas gracias!